# HttpURLConnection: handling 304 / "conditional get" -> always get a 200

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Before upgrading to support-lib v.23 I used to send my GET requests using `HttpClient` like:

```
String imsFromLastRequest = getFromPrefs( url );

Header ifModSince = new BasicHeader( "If-Modified-Since", imsFromLastRequest );
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet( url );
AndroidHttpClient.modifyRequestToAcceptGzipResponse( httpget );
httpget.addHeader( ifModSince );
HttpResponse hr = httpClient.execute( httpget );

Header[] lastMod = hr.getHeaders( "Last-Modified" );
imsFromLastRequest = lastMod[ 0 ].getValue();
saveToPrefs( url, imsFromLastRequest );
```

and that brought the 304 code back properly if the file hasn't changed.

After upgrading to support-lib v.23 I had to switch to `HttpURLConnection`:

```
HttpURLConnection huc = ( HttpURLConnection )new URL( url ).openConnection();
huc.setDoOutput( true );
huc.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
huc.setRequestProperty( "If-Modified-Since", imsFromLastRequest );
huc.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Encoding", "gzip" );
huc.connect();

imsFromLastRequest = huc.getHeaderField( "Last-Modified" );
```

In the logcat or debug I can see, that the `imsFromLastRequest` value is properly set and read to and from the request.

The problem is, that I never get the 304 code back, only 200.
What am I missing here?

I tried to use `setIfModifiedSince()` and `getHeaderFieldDate( "Last-Modified", 0 )`, but it brought nothing.

TIA!

FOLLOW-UP:

The OkHttp seems to conceal the 304 code from returning back to the caller. Instead the cached page is returned, which is bad for my case.

In order to simulate the `conditional get`-behavior I ended up comparing `imsFromLastRequest` with `getHeaderField( "Last-Modified" )` and returning 304 if they are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`huc.setUseCaches(false);`

before  `huc.connect()`

Update:

Optionally if you want to check if the response was loaded from cache, you could compare `imsFromLastRequest` with `huc.getHeaderField("Date")`.
Try something like this:

```
if(imsFromLastRequest != null && imsFromLastRequest.equalsIgnoreCase(huc.getHeaderField("Date")) {
    // your response was loaded from cache
}
```

If they are the same, the request was loaded from cache. In this case, remove the `huc.setUseCaches(false);` from your code again.

Comment: do you have access to the server logs? it would be useful to know if the response actually is a 304. It could be a problem with the request too.

Comment: does the HUC cache the response internally w/o returning the 304?

Comment: if i understand it correctly: yes. if it gets a 304 response it will check its cache and return the cached version of the file requested

Comment: indeed. the cache is intercepting the calls so that the content is always delivered back. this is bad for my case